# Roman Numerals. What are valid Subtractives? e.g. Is VL valid for 45?

Tags: number-systems

"Standard" syntax for Roman Numerals seem to always show 45 = XLV.

I wrote a little program to convert roman numerals to integers, so I started wondering what is valid in subtractive notation and what isn't.  For example, 495 is much shorter as VD rather than CDXCV

Are only some characters (I,X,C) considered valid in Subtractive notation?

Are our conclusions based on specific historical instructions, or just lack of certain kinds of examples?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be XXXXV

Comment: The convention is that $I$ can precede $X$ or $V$, $X$ can precede $L$ or $C$, and $C$ can precede $D$ or $M$, and no other subtractive notations are allowed. Have you looked at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral)?  It discusses the history in detail.

Comment: I did look at the Wikipedia article.  However, it differentiates between "standard" notation and a set of alternatives. I could not conclude therefore that it's list of alternatives were exhaustive.  Rather, historically there seems to be quite a bit of variation.

Comment: Yes; as the article says, “Usage in ancient Rome varied greatly and remained inconsistent in medieval and modern times.”

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: XLV is the usual notation, I think.

Comment: @TonyK: No! 45 = XXXXV, 55 = XXXXXV, 65 = XXXXXXV

Comment: @MJD - so should my program accept VL or reject it?  One of the references on the wiki article indicates that some word processors will generate MIM for 1999 for example.  Not going to ruin my day, but was just hoping for a more definite answer...

Comment: @Tuk-Fey: Now you're just making stuff up.

Comment: I can't tell you what your program *should* do, because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BitBlitz: MJD's answer looks definite to me! V can't precede L, so VL should be rejected.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, I'm just kidding. Peace! :)

Comment: Here's [a picture I took of a building in Philadelphia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/The_Pitcairn_Building%2C_Philadelphia_%281%29.jpg) which bears the nonstandard date $MDCDI$.  The standard notation would be $MCMI$.